# How can I serialize this class?

Tags: c#, wpf, serialization, grid, inputbinding

I have the following class (snippet):

```
[Serializable]
public class CustomRadPane : RadPane
{
    Grid grid;
    System.Windows.Controls.Label label;
    Rows rows;
    ListView listView;
```

I try to serialize it like this:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(pane.Content.GetType());
```

But when I try to serialize it, I get an exception:

> "There was an error reflecting type 'System.Windows.Controls.Grid'."

The inner exception is:

> "There was an error reflecting property 'InputBindings'."

Now, I guess the InputBindings of the Grid in the pane is what is causing issues...any idea how I can ignore this attribute in the XML? Or, if there is another way to get around this issue?

Comment: Why do people always insist on serializing the GUI instead of the data...

Comment: Not the question at hand but, because its more elegant.

Comment: Use [XamlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.aspx) and [XamlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlwriter.aspx) to serialize/deserialize WPF Elements.

Comment: @Alexandru: I'll have to greatly disagree.

Comment: Really, don't do it, it makes no sense at all and will cause problems you never want to deal with. Serialize the data--

Comment: This is getting off topic, guys. :P I'm stubborn. So what? I wanted to know how to do it, and I got my answer.

Comment: Did you try using the `DataContractSerializer` for this

Comment: There are cases where you need to serialize GUI, for example when creating a dynamic form editor that stores XAML forms in a database as XML.

Comment: @AdolfoPerez Sounds like a bad design. If you have such an editor, you should describe the configuration of its content as data and store this data in the db. IMHO, this is the much better approach. Always separate visualization from data, if you want to be flexible in the future.

Comment: I went with just serializing the data, for the record...but its still good to know how to serialize the user interface. Cheers!